# SceneGraph video player not working with certain M3U8 URLs

Tags: video-streaming, roku, brightscript, scenegraph

The SceneGraph video player `(CreateObject("roSGNode", "Video"))` appears to be unable to handle HLS via certain M3U8 URLs. I can get other web-based/HTML5 players, as well as Apple's AVPlayer (tvOS and iOS) to accept and stream from the URL just fine, but whenever I try to feed it to the video player in my Roku app, it errors almost immediately with an error complaining about no valid bitrates:

```
errorCode: -5
dbgmsg: "buffer: Loop: demux: Errors seen on all bitrates: extra: type:buffer:is_init:0: lasterror: 970: retry:0"
errorMsg: "no valid bitrates"
```

When I test with the Roku Stream Tester, I get a similar error: "Video PlayBack Error: no valid bitrates". I have also verified in all of Roku's sample video player apps, so I'm relatively certain it's not a client side code issue. I can reproduce on multiple devices.

I cracked open the m3u8 and am wondering if it's an encoding issue? Maybe Roku isn't playing nice with these codecs?:

`#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=361293,BANDWIDTH=1335394,RESOLUTION=1280x720,CODECS="mp4a.40.2,avc1.640020"`

The URLs are coming from a third party, so I don't have access to the manifest or any ability to change encoding.

Is this a bug or am I missing something? Thanks!